# Updating the url bar from the webapp to represent the current state

Tags: java, ajax, url, jsf, jsf-2

I would like to basically do what Jason asked for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457/modify-address-bar-url-in-ajax-app-to-match-current-state)

In one sentence, I would like the url bar to represent the state of the AJAX application so that I can allow to bookmark it as well as allow the user to return to the previous state by using the back/forward buttons in the browser.

The difference for me (From what Jason asked) is that I am using JSF 2.0.
I've read that JSF 2.0 added the ability to use get, but I am not sure what the correct way to use this.

Thanks for the help.

**Further Clarification**

If I understand correctly, to be able to bookmark specific states in the AJAX webapp I will have to use the location.hash. Am I correct? I'm trying to achieve a gmail-like behaviour in the sense that, while the app is complete AJAXified and no redirects occur, I can still use Back/Forward and bookmark (And that's why I would like the URL bar to be updated from the AJAX app itself and not through redirection)

**Update**

Just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475076/retrieve-the-fragment-hash-from-a-url-and-inject-the-values-into-the-bean) similar question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The difference for me (From what Jason asked) is that I am using JSF 2.0. I've read that JSF 2.0 added the ability to use get, but I am not sure what the correct way to use this.*

Please note that this is not the same as maintaining the Ajax state. It usually happens by fragment identifiers (the part starting with `#` in URL, also known as hashbang). JSF doesn't offer builtin components/functionality for this. As far I have also not seen a component library which does that. You may however find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475076/retrieve-the-fragment-hash-from-a-url-and-inject-the-values-into-the-bean) useful to get started with a homegrown hash fragment processor in JSF.

As to using GET requests, just use `<h:link>`, `<h:outputLink>` or even `<a>` to create GET links. You can supply request parameters in the `h:` components by `<f:param>`. E.g.

```
<h:link value="Edit product" outcome="product/edit">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{product.id}" />
</h:link>
```

In the `product/edit.xhtml` page you can define parameters to set and actions to execute upon a GET request

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{productEditor.id}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{productEditor.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

In the request or view scoped bean associated with `product/edit.xhtml` page -in this example `#{productEditor}`-, you just define the properties and the listener method. The listener method will be executed after all properties are been gathered, converted, validated and updated in the model.

```
private Long id;
private Product product;

public void init() {
    product = productService.find(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. If I understand correctly, to be able to bookmark specific states in the AJAX webapp I will have to use the location.hash. Am I correct? I'm trying to achieve a gmail-like behaviour in the sense that, while the app is complete AJAXified and no redirects occur, I can still use Back/Forward and bookmark (And that's why I would like the URL bar to be updated from the AJAX app itself and not through redirection)

Comment: Yes you are correct and yes I already understood the functional requirement. Ajax-navigating is unfortunately not exactly trivial as it would need to be specific to the JSF impl and component library used. I *guess*, if Cagatay Civici from PrimeFaces get enough feature requests on that, he will implement it as one of the first JSF component libs with Ajax bookmarkability (shebangs/hashbangs).

Comment: So is your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475076/retrieve-the-fragment-hash-from-a-url-and-inject-the-values-into-the-bean) the solution?

Comment: Yes, you can use it. Thank you for the link, I totally forgot that I ever posted this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd use AJAX to prevent complete page refreshes. AFAIK all current browsers would issue a page refresh if you change the base uri. Thus you would have to use the hash part as suggested in the question you provided.

We had a similar problem and did something like this:

1. We settled for the fact that users cannot bookmark the url.
2. For URLs that should be unique/bookmarkable we used different links that issue a redirect. Those URLs are provided in a sitemap.
3. For browser back, we added an intermediate page after login. This page does navigation and a redirect to the application. The navigation is stored in the session and when the server gets a navigation request (which can be a history back) the corresponding state is restored. A browser back opens that intermediate page which issues a redirect along with a navigation request on the server side.