# IE6/7 Back/Forward button don't change window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2

I have an ajax webapp (JSF 2.0) that uses hash for navigation.

I've used both event firing with help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475076/retrieve-the-fragment-hash-from-a-url-and-inject-the-values-into-the-bean/3477285#3477285) and `setInterval()` to check for value change in older browsers (Mainly IE6+7).

The Javascript code that does this:

```
window.onload = window.onhashchange = function() {
    lastHash = window.location.hash; // To save a refresh on browsers that don't need it.
    var fragment = document.getElementById('fragment');
    fragment.value = window.location.hash;
    fragment.onchange();
}

// Old Browsers That don't support onhashchange...
var lastHash = window.location.hash;
function checkFragment() {
    if (window.location.hash != lastHash) {
        lastHash = window.location.hash;
        var fragment = document.getElementById('fragment');
        fragment.value = window.location.hash;
        fragment.onchange();
    }
}
```

This works nicely. Meaning, when I change the value of the hash the AJAX app gets the notification and updates.
One instance in which this doesn't work is IE 6/7. When I press Back/Forward buttons, I can see the url bar gets updated with the correct hash values, but the `windows.location.hash` doesn't seem to change and so my `SetEvent()` function doesn't detect the change.

Anyone found a solution to this?
Thanks!

Comment: Ummm ... looks to me like javascript, not java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [jQuery Hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) to avoid IE6/7 compatibility headaches. You can find [code example here](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/). It can be altered as follows for your case.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-hashchange.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(window).hashchange(function(){
            $('#fragment').val(location.hash).change();
        });

        $(window).hashchange();
    });
</script>
```